# Change the array of struct field value in Julia

Tags: julia

Let's say I want to define the following object

```
mutable struct Coord
x::Float
y::Float
end
```

and create a vector of the coordinate

```
coordVec = Vector{Coord}(undef, 3)
```

by using for loop we can define the value of coordinate in the `coordVec`, but how to assign a new value of the coordinate? I have try following way but not working

```
coordVec[1].x = 3.1
(p->p.x).(coordVec)[1] = 3.1
```

Comment: Note that `Float` is not a standard type. You probably want to use `Float64` or `Float32`.

Comment: @FrançoisFévotte thanks, noted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your array `coordVec` is uninitialized because you used the `undef` to construct the array, meaning its values are undefined:

```
julia> coordVec = Vector{Coord}(undef, 3)
3-element Array{Coord,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

And therefore you can't update the fields. If you put `Coord` objects in your array you can update them as expected:

```
julia> coordVec[2] = Coord(1, 2)
Coord(1.0, 2.0)

julia> coordVec[2].x = 3.0
3.0

julia> coordVec
3-element Array{Coord,1}:
 #undef
    Coord(3.0, 2.0)
 #undef
```

Answer (score 2):

When initializing the whole `Vector` at once it is also always to consider broadcasting (this assume that `Coord` has `Float64` fields:

```
julia> Coord.([1.,2.,3.], 4:6)
3-element Array{Coord,1}:
 Coord(1.0, 4.0)
 Coord(2.0, 5.0)
 Coord(3.0, 6.0)
```